# Parser error in c# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

My system shuts down and then my application starts giving me the below error

Parser Error

> Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message:

> 'Project_management.ProjectDetails_Datewise' is not allowed here
>   because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

I have deleted folders from temporary file.

[image]

Comment: [Might be this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2057817/314291) - ensure `.aspx`, `.aspx.cs` code behind and designer cs are all in the same namespace.

Comment: What does the class declaration for `Project_management.ProjectDetails_Datewise` look like? Have you compared what's on your local machine with what's in source control?

Comment: Is the aspx.cs page inherited with System.Web.UI.Page??

Comment: Nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Comment: Show us the codebehind

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file same way you have tried the last time. Check the difference between both file's aspx page (not the codebehind).

Copy the namespace from newly create file and it will work.