# parsing error - what causes it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

[image]

The above error appeared on a browser page, and it says:

> Parser Error Message: 'CreatingNetTutorial._default' is not allowed
>   here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

I'm an EF newbie trying out EF.  Here is the beginnings of my main code:

```
namespace CreatingNetTutorial.Model
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Book myBook = new Book()
            {
                BookTitle = "Harry Potter",
                Date = DateTime.Now,
                Year = 2005
            };

            BookDbContext db = new BookDbContext();
            db.Books.Add(myBook);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

My .aspx which contains basically nothing except the first line, which the message complains about:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CreatingNetTutorial._default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My code includes EF, and I'm writing it to create a database and store data on it, but haven't created tables on it yet.  This runs fine except for this parsing error, no other errors.  What does this message I quoted above mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057817/parser-error-default-is-not-allowed-here-because-it-does-not-extend-class-s

Comment: Try changing 'CreatingNetTutorial._default' to 'CreatingNetTutorial.Model._default'

Comment: @whymatter- Thanks, that did it.  My tables were created.  I tried everything else but that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the complete namespace of class _default

CreatingNetTutorial.Model

`<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="CreatingNetTutorial.Model._default" %>`

Regards,